# Http GET method in axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-context

I have a problem with axios. Can I send data in the body of a GET request? I'm working with a clientAxios constant, which has the configuration data.

I realized a GET request like this:

```
const getOrganizations = async email => {
    try {
      const response = await clientAxios.get('/organizations', email);
      console.log(response);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ORGANIZATIONS,
        payload: response.data
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  }
```

But, when I check the backend console, no data was sent in the body request.

Comment: While I'm not sure it's strictly forbidden by the spec, sending a body with a GET request is very unusual; are you sure you need to?

Comment: It's unconventional to send a body with a GET, it has no semantic meaning (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/3001761).